# Form validation with Jquery not working with Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've just come across a problem with my form validation for a simple checkbox in Google Chrome:

```
$("#index_form").submit(function(event) {

            var device = $("select[name=device]").val();
            var agree = $("input[name=agree]").checked;

            if (device==0) {
                $("#device").html(" <b style='color:red'>You must enter a device!</b>");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if (!agree) {
                alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions!");
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
```

In Chrome the `alert` message keeps displaying no matter if its checked or not.  In Safari, its fine.  I've reset Chrome and even tried it on two different computers, and the problem still persists.  The checkbox is inside a `table` which is `included` with the `php` function.  All the other validation code including the `select` element works well.  The only way I can carry on working is to disable the line of code thats causing the problem.

Comment: One way to resolve it would be to use the HTML5 `required` attribute alongside the JavaScript. Chrome supports this, but it won't cause any issue with older browsers that don't.

Comment: Thanks - Just had a play with the example from w3 schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checked` is a DOM element property, not jQuery one. So use instead:

```
var agree = $("input[name=agree]").prop('checked');
```

Comment: Excellent! works a treat.  I've just made a comment in my code to remind me that I should start distinguishing between JQuery and the DOM!